# Lazy C++ (LZZ) rule files for Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rules, lazy-c++

Has anyone made LZZ rule files for Visual C++ 2010 so you can add .lzz files to a project and compile without seeing the intermediate .cpp and .h files?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. What's wrong with the intermediary files?

Checkout: [How do I make build rules in cmake to preprocess lazy C++ .lzz files that generate .h and .cpp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687136/)

Comment: The problem with the answer you link to is that the solution explorer only shows the generated .cpp and .h files (which the developer shouldn't touch), and not the .lzz files.