# Use cmake to conditionally generate source input files

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cmake, precompiled-headers

I'm using cmake with C++ project. I want to use precompiled headers in GCC.

I want to run `cmake` once and then, when running `make`, I want this actions to happen:

1. Run my custom tool (python script) on whole source tree. It generates precompiled.h headers in some subdirectories. It's purpose is to scan *.h and *.cpp for #include's and move them to common precompiled.h files.
2. generate GCC's precompiled headers (`g++ -c precompiled.h -o precompiled.h.gch`) ONLY when precompiled.h file has changed after step 1.
3. build outdated targets (after step 2. because I want to use .gch file)

I've managed to add dependencies, so whenever I build any target, my python script's target is executed (this is ugly, because now every target has to depend on single global_init target). Also I can modify my python script, so it doesn't modify precompiled.h when it is not necessary.

But I don't know what to do next. Is there any way to tell cmake that it should run my custom script and AFTER THAT determine if precompiled.h.gch must be created? Now it is always build (this file contains many #include's, so it takes some time). Basically:

1. Execute python script -> precompiled.h MAY BE updated
2. Examine precompiled.h timestamp and if it's newer -> build precompiled.h.gch
3. Standard compilation steps

I've looked in many places, but cmake's (and make's) way of calculating dependencies seems too weak to accomplish this task.

In this question:
[lazy c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687136/how-do-i-make-build-rules-in-cmake-to-preprocess-lazy-c-lzz-files-that-generat)
compilation always happens after lazycpp is executed. This would not be optimal in my case.

Comment: To aid your search this is called "order only dependency" in GNU makefiles (prerequisities after the `|` character in a target).  That is, you may wish to clarify that what you want to do is have a target prerequisite which must also be called prior to a target, but does not cause the execution of that target.

Comment: Hmm, even that might not help now that I think closely.  Easiest approach is to likely just have your Python script call `g++` when it needs to regenerate the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following CMake commands may serve as a starting point for your project:

```
add_custom_target(scanner COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scanner.py"
    COMMENT "Scanning include files ..."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

This command covers step 1. It invokes your python script which may update the existing `precompiled.h` files in `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT precompiled.h.gch
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} 
    -c "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/precompiled.h" -o precompiled.h.gch
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/precompiled.h"
    IMPLICIT_DEPENDS CXX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/precompiled.h")

add_custom_target(generate_precompiled DEPENDS
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/precompiled.h.gch")

add_dependencies(generate_precompiled scanner)
```

These commands cover step 2. The precompiled header is generated with a custom command which depends on `precompiled.h` and [implicitly](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_custom_command) on other headers that `precompiled.h` includes.
`precompiled.h.gch` is generated in the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` directory.
Because the precompiled header generation requires `precompiled.h` to be updated by the python script, we add a target level dependency on the target `scanner`.

```
include_directories(BEFORE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(main main.cpp)

set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-include precompiled.h -H")

add_dependencies(main generate_precompiled)
```

These commands add standard compilation steps which generate an executable `main`. The precompiled header is included as a default header with gcc's `-include` switch. The `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` which contains `precompiled.h.gch` is added as an include directory. gcc will pick up `precompiled.h.gch` from there when precompiled.h is included (see [Using Precompiled Headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)).

Finally the target dependency on `generate_precompiled` ensures that the precompiled header is updated if necessary.

Comment: Your solution works, but my source tree is a bit complicated. I would like to place _one_ scanner target _only_ in root directory and in subdirectories place precompiled.h.gch commands (I have some sub-libraries). To do this I have to write (in firstLib's subdir):<br/>add_custom_target(generate_precompiled_firstLib DEPENDS precompiled.h.gch) <br/> add_dependencies(generate_precompiled generate_precompiled_firstLib) <br/> but now the order of build is wrong(first, make builds .gch file using old header, then it runs scanner to regenerate it)

Comment: You could do a `add_dependencies(generate_precompiled_firstLib scanner)` in firstLib's subdir.

Comment: I did it and it works. Thanks! Your help in giving me the proper sequence of dependencies helps me better understand and use cmake.